# Sendmessage not working properly inside of a method definition

Tags: c++, winapi

In order to prevent the WM_LBUTTONUP event from being flooded with code, I decided to make a class method that contains the code which initially triggered on WM_LBUTTONUP.

Example:

```
 case WM_LBUTTONUP:
 {//Code that used to trigger on WM_LBUTTONUP below:
  x=4;
  y=2;
  SendMessage(hWnd, CUSTOM_WMMESSAGE, NULL, NULL);
}//The above SendMessage() call works
```

Method Definition:

```
void Dog::bark(HWND hindow, INT wm_message)
{//All code that used to trigger on WM_LBUTTON up was moved to this method
 x=4;
 y=2;
 SendMessage(hwindow, wm_message, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Afterward:

```
case WM_LBUTTONUP:
{Object.bark();}
//When SendMessage was called this way (inside of a method definition)
//it did not work!
```

**Problem:**

SendMessage() worked on WM_LBUTTONUP when it was not used inside of a class method. However, once I called SendMessage() from a class method on WM_LBUTTONUP, the message was not sent (which means, SendMessage() did not, or does not work when called from a class method).

**Please Note:**

The method definition is not in the same file as WM_LBUTTON up (and I would like to keep it that way, to prevent main.cpp from being filled with too much code :) )

**Edit**

The file name which contains the class' definition is called Dog.hpp 
I included Dog.hpp inside of main.cpp. 
I have successfully created other class methods (inside of dog.hpp) which worked, so I know there's nothing wrong with the class or the header file code. The only problem is, that when the SendMessage() function is called inside of dog.hpp, as apposed to being called in main.cpp, it does not work.

Comment: SendMessage doesn't know if it's being called from inside a class method. In fact, it knows *nothing* about classes at all. We need more information. How does it not work? Does the code fail to compile? Does it compile but not run? Does it run but the message does not get posted? What does SendMessage return? Waht does GetLastError return?

Comment: Does the file that has the method definition know of the SendMessage method? I mean did you include the header of the class that provides the SendMessage method?

Comment: Sorry, I initially wrote what I did with the header file, and somehow erased it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.bark()` expects input parameters that you are not passing in to it.  You need to do this instead:

```
case WM_LBUTTONUP:
{
    Object.bark(hWnd, CUSTOM_WMMESSAGE);
    break; // <-- this is missing in your original code as well!
}
```

Comment: Thank you, though I already included hWnd, Custom_WMMessage in my original code, I forgot to put it in the example above. It turns out it was another portion of my code that was not working, send message works in a class definition, but I accepted your answer anyways because you were absolutely right.